# Is there a way to move open window between linux machines?

Tags: linux, external-display, x-server

I have two computers, both of which run Linux. My main computer is where I do most of my work on and my large display computer which sits in another room from which I give presentations and play short videos. I would like to move a window that I have open on my main machine to the display computer.

Also, while I am giving a presentation, I would like to show the presentation on the display computer and have either a copy of that screen or a presenter display on my main rig.

I have looked in quite a few places, and I think the way to do it would be through the Xserver, but I can't seem to find the correct combination of options and displays.

Is there a fairly easy way to do this? If need be, I could script it to give myself a single command to use.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is: it is called Winswitch, you can find it in your repos, or [here](https://winswitch.org/downloads/). It is a derivative of xpra, and *apt-cache show winswitch* describes the program thus:

> tool to start and control remote sessions; 
>    supports both seamless applications (via Xpra, NX and ssh)
>    and full remote desktops (via NX, VNC, RDP).
>    Once a session has been started via winswitch,
>    it can be displayed on any other networked machine running
>    the winswitch client.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using X11 Forwarding. One simple way to achieve this, is the following option in [ssh](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh):

```
ssh -X hostname
```

Now, when you start an X11 application in this session on the remote host, the corresponding window will appear on you local host.

Comment: only new windows, opened through this ssh session will go to the host starting it... which doesn't seem to be the expected feature.